# Url Routing with symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

i  have started to  learn  symfony  framework by reading  joobet-propel book.i was  in  URL Routing  chapter ,i   tried every sample  in my  sample  application.But it gives me error.
Compeletely My issue:

a small part of routing.yml file:

```
bookmark_deneme_user:

url: /post/:title_slug/:id/:summary_slug

class: sfPropelRoute

options: { model: Bookmark, type: object }

param: { module: post, action: show }

requirements:

id: \d+

sf_method: [get]
```

i have an  Object Bookmark with title,summary,id and  url, and  i want to  show  one bookmark in detail  with  the  url  title/id/summary  ,so i wrote  abovementioned yml  and  iused "echo url_for('bookmark_deneme_user', $bookmark)" in xxxSuccess.php URL in Page is  true  but  when i click  to url for showing the bookmark in detail. it  gives me this error:

> 404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception
>
> Action "post/deneme" does not exist.

"deneme"is title of  selected bookmark ,why it dont use  id property .how can i resolve that problem?

Comment: can you post the complete generated url ?

Comment: do you have getTitleSlug and getSummarySlug methods in your Bookmark object? as they are needed by your route rule, and as gpilotino stated post a generated url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've left the default route in your yml - if you leave it in, it needs to be below the route you've added, as symfony will use the first route that matches.

(default route is the one that has the url /:module/:action)